# Layer list gets cropped to drawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, layer-list

This is the desired drawable which I am trying to build.

[image: Desired result]

The problem:

As I know layer-list size depends on the last item in it. But if I use `android:drawable` inside tag `<item>`, layer list gets cropped to the drawable size doesn't matter in what position it is.

Here is my `swipe_close.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="34dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_close_swipe" />
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="34dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="10dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#E6E6E6" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And the `ic_close_swipe.xml`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="39dp"
  android:height="39dp"
  android:viewportWidth="39"
  android:viewportHeight="39">
    <path
        android:pathData="M37.7269,5.2568C38.5079,4.4757 38.5079,3.2094 37.7269,2.4283L36.5711,1.2726C35.7901,0.4916 34.5238,0.4916 33.7427,1.2726L20.7758,14.2395C19.9947,15.0206 18.7284,15.0206 17.9473,14.2395L4.9804,1.2726C4.1994,0.4916 2.933,0.4916 2.152,1.2726L0.9962,2.4283C0.2152,3.2094 0.2152,4.4757 0.9962,5.2568L13.9632,18.2237C14.7442,19.0048 14.7442,20.2711 13.9632,21.0521L0.9962,34.0191C0.2152,34.8001 0.2152,36.0665 0.9962,36.8475L2.152,38.0032C2.933,38.7843 4.1994,38.7843 4.9804,38.0032L17.9473,25.0363C18.7284,24.2553 19.9947,24.2553 20.7758,25.0363L33.7427,38.0032C34.5238,38.7843 35.7901,38.7843 36.5711,38.0032L37.7269,36.8475C38.5079,36.0665 38.5079,34.8001 37.7269,34.0191L24.7599,21.0521C23.9789,20.2711 23.9789,19.0048 24.7599,18.2237L37.7269,5.2568Z"
        android:fillColor="#C4C4C4"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend changing `swipe_close.xml` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="34dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="25dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_close_swipe"
        android:left="25dp"
        android:right="25dp"
        android:top="25dp" />
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="10dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#E6E6E6" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That what I did, but it's not a proper solution. Thx.

Comment: umm ... Did you use the drawable that I provided? I added the padding around the `ic_close_swipe`. Can you please explain a little bit why you think this is not a proper solution?

Comment: Yes I used padding, but 24.5 and not 25.
It's not good because this padding depends on drawable that I use. So if i will change drawable, and it will be smaller or bigger, the whole layer list will be resized. I want to be able to set layer list size in swipe_close.xml. Thanks again for quick response!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I think you cannot get something as dynamic as you want which will work for every drawable. You will have to put the inset or padding around your drawable to fit the drawable inside the layer-list. Let me know if you find anything else. Good luck. :)